# What is the word of "he/she is not the project owner, but he/she is also notified?"

Tags: single-word-requests

As the title, is there any correct word to address the meaning?
I come up with "notifier" but seems not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps he/she is a **stakeholder**

> A person, group or organization that has interest or concern in an
>   organization. Stakeholders can affect or be affected by the
>   organization's actions, objectives and policies. Some examples of key
>   stakeholders are creditors, directors, employees, government (and its
>   agencies), owners (shareholders), suppliers, unions, and the community
>   from which the business draws its resources.
>
> Read more:
>   http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/stakeholder.html#ixzz4FVH4FqKt

or an **interested party**

> any of the people or organizations who may be affected by a situation,
>   or who are hoping to make money out of a situation: Employees,
>   suppliers, customers, and other interested parties are anxiously
>   awaiting news about the takeover bid. Details of the contract will be
>   made available for any interested party to look at.
>
> Source:
>   http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interested-party